# Updating favorite tags in different tabs overwrites earlier changes

Tags: bug, tags, tag-watching

I've found a reproducible issue while editing my "Favorite Tags".

**To reproduce:**

1. While logged in, open two browsers windows and visit a StackExchange site.
2. In the first window, click the "edit" link in the Favorite Tags section.
3. Type in a new favorite tag, and click "Add".
4. Switch to the other window, and add another new tag.
5. Refresh each page.

**Expected result:**

After refreshing either page, both new tags will be displayed in the order they were added.

**Actual Result:**

Only the second tag is saved, and the first one is overwritten. It appears whatever was visible at the time of adding the newest tag will be persisted.

Comment: I reproduced that on Seasoned Advice using Safari on iPad 2. I tried a few different times, but even though a new tag appears in the saved list on both pages, the tag saved first disappears when the pages are refreshed. Adding ignored tags works as it should. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Also on Google Chrome